# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Tags: angular, bootstrap, typescript, api, frontend

vengo aca con un problemita estoy haciendo una app en angular con una api en .net core con db Sql y tengo un error al momento que intento guardar la información de mi formulario al parecer no me reconoce los valores ingresados no se si me falto algo o si hay alguna otra forma de guardar los datos en la función, les comparto el html y el TS como tambien el error que me sale en la consola quedo atento  de ante mano gracias

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  Validators,
  FormControl
} from '@angular/forms';
import {
  TarjetaCredito
} from 'src/app/models/tarjetaCredito';
import {
  TarjetaService
} from 'src/app/services/tarjeta.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tarjeta-credito',
  templateUrl: './tarjeta-credito.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tarjeta-credito.component.css']
})
export class TarjetaCreditoComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup | any;


  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private tarjetaService: TarjetaService) {

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: 0,
      titular: ["", [Validators.required]],
      numeroTarjeta: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(16), Validators.minLength(16)]],
      fechaExpiracion: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5), Validators.minLength(5)]],
      cvv: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(3), Validators.minLength(3)]]
    });


  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  guardarTarjeta() {
    const tarjeta: TarjetaCredito = {
      titular: this.form.get('titular').value,
      numeroTarjeta: this.form.get('numeroTarjeta').value,
      fechaExpedicion: this.form.get('fechaExpedicion').value,
      cvv: this.form.get('cvv').value


    }
    this.tarjetaService.guardarTarjeta(tarjeta).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("guardado!!!!");

    })

  }

}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="guardarTarjeta()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
          <i class="fas fa-user-circle" [class.green-icon]="this.form.get('titular').valid" [class.red-icon]="this.form.get('titular').invalid && this.form.get('titular').touched"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Titular" formControlName="titular">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
          <i class="fas fa-credit-card" [class.green-icon]="this.form.get('numeroTarjeta').valid" [class.red-icon]="this.form.get('numeroTarjeta').invalid && this.form.get('numeroTarjeta').touched"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero de Tarjeta" formControlName="numeroTarjeta" maxlength="16" minlength="16">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-7">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
              <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt" [class.green-icon]="this.form.get('fechaExpiracion').valid" [class.red-icon]="this.form.get('fechaExpiracion').invalid && this.form.get('fechaExpiracion').touched"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/AAA" formControlName="fechaExpiracion" maxlength="5" minlength="5">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
              <i class="fas fa-key" [class.green-icon]="this.form.get('cvv').valid" [class.red-icon]="this.form.get('cvv').invalid && this.form.get('cvv').touched"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CVV" formControlName="cvv" maxlength="3" minlength="3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form group">
    <button id="boton1" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid"> <i class="fas fa-database"></i> Aceptar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

[aca es el error que me sale al momento de intentar guardar la infomacion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Ui5.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Ui5.png)

este es el bendito error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando creas el `FormGroup` estas asignando un control a una propiedad con nombre **`fechaExpiracion`**:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  ...
  fechaExpiracion: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5), Validators.minLength(5)]],
  ...
});
```

Este nombre no coincide con el `string` que estás indicando en el `this.form.get` de `guardarTarjeta`, en el que pones **`fechaExpedicion`**:

```
const tarjeta: TarjetaCredito = {
  ...
  fechaExpedicion: this.form.get('fechaExpedicion').value,
  ...
}
```

un saludo